# JQuery Datatables overlapped when using column filtering

Tags: datatables, bootstrap-4, chart.js

I have a Jquery Datatable inside a bootstrap div. The Bootstrap row is divided between a Datatable and a Chartjs chart.

When initializing the DataTable without any options, the layout is maintained fine without any overlapping. But when I added the following code for adding column filtering option, the layout is broken.

```
$('#example').DataTable( {
 initComplete: function () {
   this.api().columns().every( function () {
    var column = this;
    var select = $('<select><option value=""></option></select>')
    .appendTo( $(column.footer()).empty() )
    .on( 'change', function () {
     var val = $.fn.dataTable.util.escapeRegex(
      $(this).val()
     );
column
  .search( val ? '^'+val+'$' : '', true, false )
  .draw();
  } );
column.data().unique().sort().each( function ( d, j ) {
  select.append( '<option value="'+d+'">'+d+'</option>' )
} );
} );
}
} );
```

I noticed the lowermost code is the one causing the issues. How do i fix this?

JSFiddle [for the code](http://jsfiddle.net/Lo52km1r/7/)

Comment: Hi, my friend. Could you clarify about the layout broken?

Comment: @Tomato32 Please click on the JSFiddle link. The chart is flowing on top of the table.

Comment: There is nothing wrong , not flowing on top of the table

Comment: @DavidJawHpan: Yeah. I don't see any problem with this UI :))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your table is wider than the Bootstrap column it occupies and it overflows to the graph column.

You could either

1. make the table responsive, so that it will occupy only the columns space. See https://datatables.net/extensions/responsive/
2. or you can just add `overflow: scroll` style to the column that includes the table.